# cout/cin does not name a type error

Tags: c++

Whats wrong with this code to keep on receiving this error?

The error only happened when instead of putting "distanceFormula" in main, I made it it's own class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class distanceFormula {
    public:
int speed;
int time;
int distance;

cout << "What is the speed?" << endl;
cin >> speed;

cout << "How long did the action last?" << endl;
cin >> time;


distance = speed * time;

cout << "The distance traveled was " << distance << endl;
};




int main()
{
distanceFormula ao
ao.distanceFormula;

return 0;
};
```

Comment: Why you made its own class? Did you even compile your code??

Comment: Distinguish function and class.

Comment: `ao.distanceFormula;` What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Then you have `class distanceFormula { ...  ...  };` but define what looks to be a function instead of a class.

Comment: I say its time to read your book. You need to understand the difference between a class and a function and then how to call a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the class declaration can only contain members, which can either be **data** or **function** declarations, and optionally **access specifiers**.

Wrap your code inside a function and then call that in `main` by an object

```
class distanceFormula {
public:
int speed;
int time;
int distance;
void init()
{
    cout << "What is the speed?" << endl;
    cin >> speed;

    cout << "How long did the action last?" << endl;
    cin >> time;
    distance = speed * time;
    cout << "The distance traveled was " << distance << endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    distanceFormula ao;
    ao.init();
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! the only non-criticizing one XD

Comment: @AmmarT. I updated the answer,added the reason also!

Answer (score 0):

If you still have to use a class. Here is how you do it:

```
#include <iostream>

class distanceFormula 
{
private:
    int speed; // private
    int time; // private
public:
    distanceFormula(); // constructor
    int getSpeed(); // to get
    int getTime(); // to get
    int getDistance(); // to get
    void setSpeed(int); // to set
    void setTime(int); // to set
};

distanceFormula::distanceFormula()
{
    this->time = 0;
    this->speed = 0;
}

int distanceFormula::getSpeed() 
{ 
    return this->speed;
}
int distanceFormula::getTime() 
{ 
    return this->time;
}
int distanceFormula::getDistance()
{ 
    return this->time * this->speed;
}
void distanceFormula::setSpeed(int speedVal)
{ 
    this->speed = speedVal;
}
void distanceFormula::setTime(int timeVal)
{  
    this->time = timeVal;
}


int main()
{
    distanceFormula  YourObject; // create obj
    int SpeedValue; 
    int TimeValue;
    std::cout << "Enter the Speed:";
    std::cin >> SpeedValue; // take speed

    std::cout << "Enter the Time:";
    std::cin >> TimeValue; // take time


    YourObject.setSpeed(SpeedValue); // set
    YourObject.setTime(TimeValue); // set

    std::cout << "This is the distance: " << YourObject.getDistance(); // retrieve result

    getchar(); // wait
    return 0;
}
```